# Newman unable to read the environment on MacBook (zsh: -e command not found)

Tags: postman, zsh, newman

I'm trying to perform API calls with Newman on zsh on  McBook.

I tried this command:

```js
newman run https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{{$collectionID}}?apikey={{$APIkey}}
 -e https://api.getpostman.com/environments/{{$envID}}?apikey={$APIkey}
```

, but it doesn't recognize the collection:

```js
(zsh: no matches found: https://api.getpostman.com/environments/{{$collectionID}}?apikey={$APIkey}})
```

When i try with quotes, it doesn't recognize the env parameter:

```js
newman run "https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{{$collectionID}}?apikey={{$APIkey}}"
 -e "https://api.getpostman.com/environments/{{$envID}}?apikey={$APIkey}"
```

```js
zsh: command not found: -e
```

Comment: The quoted form should work, but it needs to be on a single line. Note that the curly braces (`{...}` and `{{...}}`) will be passed to the `newman` command. Are they part of the url?

Comment: Without quotes it does not make sense, since a question mark is a special character for zsh (that's why you get _no matches found_. As for the correct quoted form, I don't know what `newman run` is atually doing, so I can't say much - except that I would do a `type newman`, to make sure that really the binary _newman_  is executed and not something else, which is shadowing.

Comment: I just wonder: Shouldn't it be the otherway round, `newman run -e "....env..."  ".... collection ...."`?

Comment: @user1934428 -e is used to call the environment parameter, so i don't think that it's the correct way. You should call the collection that add the paramters.

Comment: @Gairfowl My bad, i realized that i hit "Enter" betwwen the collection and the env. So yeah, it should be the quoted form, in a singe line. Thanks a lot!